# Laravel fetch category and sub-category

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Table structure

```
--------------------------
|id     name    parent_id
--------------------------
|1      Memory  NULL
|2      RAM     1
```

for my features and sub-features my model as below

```
class Feature extends Model
{
    public $fillable = ['name','parent_id'];


    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Feature','parent_id');
    }

    public function child()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Feature','parent_id');
    }
}
```

Now i want to fetch parent features and sub-features,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$features = Feature::whereNull('parent_id')->with('child')->get();
```

Then

```
foreach ($features as $feature)
{
    $feature->name; // Parent
    $feature->child->name; // Child
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$f = Feature::with('child', 'parent')->get()
```

now you can have them like this :

```
$f->name;
$f->parent->name;
$f->child->name;
```